# firebase (CORS) & Refused to execute script from 'dist/bundle.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, angular, firebase

I'm creating new website by firebase and webpack ( html ,css, js ).
After deploying I get :

> Refused to execute script from 'https://xxx.online/dist/bundle.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled

and

> Improvements
> Page layout may be unexpected due to Quirks Mode
> Response was blocked by CORB (Cross-Origin Read Blocking)
> Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked a cross-origin response. 
> 5 requests
> bundle.js
> index.bundle.js
> cryptoTicker.bundle.js

I tried fixing my firebase.json and tried to add

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/dist/index.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/dist/cryptoTicker.bundle.js"></script>
```

yet it didn't work.
Any fix please?